# Facebook album creation not working properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload, image

I am trying to upload an image to face book album . I would like to upload the pictures to an album named 'God'. If there is no an albuma named Sunil, I would like to create the alum and upload the picture in to it. If there is an albuma named Sunil is already exists , the picture need to upload in it it.

I have tried the folllowing code. Now the pictures are uploaded to an album named 'Picslanda'. How can I change the album name to my own.

```php
require_once 'fbpic/library/facebook.php';

$app_id     = "xxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxxx";
$facebook   = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
  'cookie' => true
));
$fbcheck = $facebook->getUser();

if (is_null($fbcheck) or !$fbcheck or $fbcheck==0)
{
  header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,photo_upload'))}");
}
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport("http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
// add a status message
$photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', 
  array(
    'source'  => '@' .realpath("images/poovarty.jpg") ,
    'message' => 'It is a programming test'
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok , here is a example code , this code check for a album named "Wall Photos" and will upload image.jpg on that album , but the user have to approve that image as its uploaded via an application

```
<?php
include 'header.php'; // header.php is the basic auth file for facebook 
$FILE_PATH = 'image.jpg';

$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?"
        . "access_token=" . $token . '&limit=100';


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

foreach ($data->data as $d) {
    if ($d->name == 'Wall Photos')
        $ALBUM_ID = $d->id;
}


$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($FILE_PATH);

$data = $facebook->api('/'. $ALBUM_ID . '/photos', 'post', $args);
print_r($data);

?>
```