# Face book album creation is not working well

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, upload

Iam trying to upload image to facebook album. Now images are uploaded to an album having facebook app name. I would like to upload images to an album named 'Flowers'.

I am using the following code.

```
<?php
    require_once 'fbpic/library/facebook.php';

    $app_id = "xxxx";
    $app_secret = "xxxxx";
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId' => $app_id,
     'secret' => $app_secret,
     'cookie' => true
    ));
    $fbcheck= $facebook->getUser();

    if(is_null($fbcheck) or !$fbcheck or $fbcheck==0)
    {
     header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,photo_upload'))}");

    }



        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport("http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
        // add a status message
        $photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', 
            array(
                'source' => '@' .realpath("ContactUs.jpg") ,
                'message' => 'It is a programming test'
            )
        );
```

?>

Comment: Please explain more thoroughly what your problem is - you need to include any errors you're seeing from your code and a description of exactly what happens when you try to run it.

Comment: Now the images are uploaded to an album named 'MyFacebookapplicationName'. I would like to upload the images to an album named 'Flower'. Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook album creation not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755164/facebook-album-creation-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 2 in the Facebook blog post here should help: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

Answer (score 0):

To check if the album exits or not.

Do  a get on graphurl/{userId}/albums .
( You can also use FQL to do the same task)

Iterate over the list to see if album with name already exits.

If already exits 
Post the Pic with the url graphurl/{albumId}/photos

If album does not exits create the album.
Do a post on $facebookGraphUrl.'/me/albums with params name and description.

Use the album id then to post the pic on this album.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Refering [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/#photos)

You can add photos to an album by issuing an HTTP POST request to ALBUM_ID/photos with the publish_stream permissions and the following parameters.

```
    Parameter   Description         Type                    Required 
    source      Photo content       multipart/form-data     yes
    message     Photo description   string                  no
```

So, instead of

```
 $photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', 
            array(
                'source' => '@' .realpath("ContactUs.jpg") ,
                'message' => 'It is a programming test'
            )
        );
```

you should do,

```
 $photo = $facebook->api('/<your_album_id>/photos', 'POST', 
            array(
                'source' => '@' .realpath("ContactUs.jpg") ,
                'message' => 'It is a programming test'
            )
        );
```

**p.s.**
When you dont specify an album_id, facebook creates an album for you with your application name and if its already created, all photos with no album_id goes to that album